Solidworks Macro to turn off "Automatically update cut lists"
I am using PDM Pro, and want to make a macro that can run on the task scheduler to turn off "Automatically update cut lists" option.
I have recorded a macro that works, but I want to be able to run it on a specified group of files, or a folder.
I know the scheduler has a parameters table, but not sure yet on how that is done.
This works on the currently open part:
Dim swApp As Object

Dim Part As Object
Dim boolstatus As Boolean
Dim longstatus As Long, longwarnings As Long

Sub main()

Set swApp = Application.SldWorks

' Get the active document (the currently open part)
Set Part = swApp.ActiveDoc
' Check if a document is open
If Part Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "No active document found. Please open a part file and try again."
    Exit Sub
End If

Set Part = swApp.ActiveDoc
boolstatus = Part.Extension.SetUserPreferenceToggle(swUserPreferenceToggle_e.swWeldmentEnableAutomaticUpdate, 0, False)
boolstatus = Part.Extension.SetUserPreferenceToggle(swUserPreferenceToggle_e.swWeldmentCollectIdenticalBodies, 0, False)
boolstatus = Part.Extension.ForceRebuildAll()

' Save
Dim swErrors As Long
Dim swWarnings As Long
boolstatus = Part.Save3(1, swErrors, swWarnings)
Part.ClearSelection2 True
MsgBox "Auto Cut List Update disabled and part saved successfully."
End Sub


With PDM Pro, the only way to get something running on a schedule is to create a custom task. If you want to run it on-demand, you may be able to create a task with the SWTaskAddIn that comes with PDM Pro. On the "script" tab, you can put in a macro to run. I haven't done too much with customizing scripts this way so you may need to overcome some headaches with checking-out, changing, checking-in the file.
